# About ramification groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, valuation-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a field complete with respect to a valuation $v_K$ on it. Let $K<L$ be a finite Galois extension that is totally ramified, and let $G$ be its Galois group. Let $A_K$ be the ring of $v_K$ with the maximal ideal $p_K$, and $U_K$ be the units in $A_K$. Define $A_L, p_L, U_L, v_L$ similarly.

Let $G_i$ be the $i$th ramification group of $G$:
$$G_i=\{s\in G:v_L(s(a)-a)\geq i+1,\ \forall a\in A_L\}$$
Let $U_L^i$ be the filtration of $U_L$:
$$U_L^0=U_L,\quad U_L^i=1+p_L^i\ (i\geq1)$$

These definitions come from Serre's *Local Fields*. And I came across two problems reading it.

(1) **Why are $G_i$ normal subgroups?** I know it suffices to prove that
$$\forall s\in G_i,\ \forall\tau\in G,\ \forall x\in A_L,\ \tau^{-1}s\tau(x)-x\in P_L^{i+1}$$
For this I write
$$\tau^{-1}s\tau(x)-x=\tau^{-1}(s\tau(x)-\tau(x))\in\tau^{-1}(p_L^{i+1})$$
So I guess it remains to show $\tau^{-1}(p_L^{i+1})\subset p_L^{i+1}$. How can this be done?

(2) **What are the canonical isomorphisms $U^i_L/U^{i+1}_L\cong p^i_L/p^{i+1}_L$?** In the books it says to pass the correspondence
$$x\in p_L^i\leftrightarrow 1+x\in U_L^i$$
to the quotients. Does it mean to consider the mapping
$$p_L^i\to U_L^i/U_L^{i+1}\\x\mapsto(1+x)U_L^i$$
and then prove it induces an isomorphism?

I am new at studying algebraic number theory, and may not be familiar with some "well-known" facts. So I would appreciate it if you could provide more detailed explanations. Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE:**
For part (2), I defined the mapping
$$\phi:U_L^i=1+p_L^i\to p_L^i/p_L^{i+1}\\1+x\mapsto x+p_L^{i+1}$$
and view $U_L^i$ as a multiplicative group and $p_L^i/p_L^{i+1}$ an additive group. Then 
$$\phi((1+x)(1+y))=x+y+xy+p_L^{i+1}\\=x+y+p_L^{i+1}=(x+p_L^{i+1})+(y+p_L^{i+1})\\=\phi(1+x)+\phi(1+y)$$
means it is a homomorphism. And $\phi(1+x)=\bar0\iff x\in P_L^{i+1}\iff 1+x\in U^{i+1}_L$. This says $\ker\phi=U_L^{i+1}$. Hence we have an isomorphism
$$\bar\phi:U_L^i/U_L^{i+1}\to p_L^i/p_L^{i+1}$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: For your first question: let $\tau \in G$. Since $\tau$ fixes $K$ (and hence $A_{K}$), the restriction of $\tau$ to $A_{L}$ has image in $A_{L}$, i.e. $\tau$ restricts to an $A_{K}$-algebra endomorphism of $A_{L}$. In particular, since $A_{L}$ is a discrete valuation ring with unique prime ideal $A_{L}$, $\tau^{-1}(p_{L}) = p_{L}$ (the preimage of any prime ideal under a ring homomorphism is a prime ideal). Since $\tau^{-1}$ is a ring automorphism, this implies that $\tau^{-1}(p_{L}^{i}) \subset p_{L}^{i}$ for any positive integer $i$.

Comment: Can I conclude from the arbitrariness of $\tau$ that actually $\tau(p_L^i)=p_L^i$?